# Android 6.0 needs restart after granting user permission at runtime

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I follow this guide to ask for permissions for Android 6.0, https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#support-lib

However, I have to destroy my application and re-launch to actually have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, otherwise it keeps failing for file creation.

Am I missing something?

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity)mContext,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ServiceDownload.class);
    v.getContext().startService(i);
}
```

File is created in the service and this is emulator not a real device.

Comment: It's a bug already opened in the issue tracker

Comment: @greywolf82 can you post the link to the issue? I can't find it

Comment: @SmT Here is the bug that has been reported on the issue: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2982&q=WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

If you are in need of more assistance on the topic please find this blog: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug as someone already mentioned, but I found in this question that you can add this line:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

after your permission has been granted. This is not a real fix, just helps avoid crashing.