# FileNotFoundException (permission denied) when trying to write file to sdcard in Android

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, android-permissions

As you can notice from title, I have a problem with writing file to sdcard in Android. I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823992/java-io-filenotfoundexception-permission-denied-when-trying-to-write-to-the-an) but it didn't help me. I want to write file that will be in public space on sdcard so that any other app could read it.

First, I check if sdcard is mounted:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

Then, I run this code:

```
File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    baseDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(baseDir, "file.txt");
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Log.d("NEWFILE", file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have:

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application>
...
</application>
</manifest>
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Exact error is this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1510-2908/Download/secondFile.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I'm testing my code on emulator (emulating Nexus5 API 23). My minimum required SDK version is 19 (4.4 Kitkat).

---

Also, everything works fine with writing files to private folder on sdcard with same code so I'd say former code should work too:

```
File newFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "esrxdtcfvzguhbjnk.txt");
    newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Log.d("NEWFILE", newFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Does anyone have any clue what could be the problem? Could it be that somehow KitKat 4.4 just doesn't allow writing to public space in sdcard anymore or?

Comment: What is the value you got at `Log.d("NEWFILE", file.getAbsolutePath());` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527767/open-failed-eacces-permission-denied

Comment: @Drag0 You also need to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions at Run Time, As you are testing it "Nexus5 API 23".

Comment: i guess its because of the permission handling in android m. as in deepanker's link described, you have to add a request for the permission, befor accessing the storage in android m.

Comment: @Drag0 Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) for more detail.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> 1. Everything works fine with writing files to private folder on sdcard

Beginning with Android 4.4, these permissions are not required if you're
 reading or writing only files that are private to your app. For more information, see [saving files that are app-private.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles)

> 2. FileNotFoundException (permission denied) when trying to write file to sdcard in Android

As you are trying to write the file in emulator having API 23(Marshmallow), You need to Request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission at runtime also. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) for more detail.

Comment: This works, but only second time I start my application. If I try to open file right there in onRequestPermissionsResult() callback when user then I receive the same error as before. Could it be that permission is not yet propagated to the system? This seems strange.

Comment: @Drag0 Permission is granted to your app at the same time user allow the permission.

Comment: @Drag0 Take a look at [Can't write to external storage unless app is restarted after granting permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062006/cant-write-to-external-storage-unless-app-is-restarted-after-granting-permissio) and [Android 6.0 needs restart after granting user permission at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699129/android-6-0-needs-restart-after-granting-user-permission-at-runtime) SO post. They have reported same problem like yours.

Comment: Thanks, it seems there is an issue with Android at the moment and the bug is reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2982&q=WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars