# MediaPlayer can't play my recording sound. FileNotFoundException (Permission Denied)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to record sound and then have the abillity to hear the recoded sound. I got the filepath but the MediaPlayer won't play it either. I've seen some examples of MediaPlayer and I thought it would only be like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();


    mp.setDataSource(path); // + File.separator + fileName
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

My path is: /storage/emulated/0/recordings/music recordings/Audio recording 2017-02-06 00-17-12.amr

Logcat:

> 02-06 00:21:23.151 12308-12391/com.example.studerande.upg32 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7aea6a7400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7aea5d6fc0
>   02-06 00:21:28.633 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 E/recordapp: File exist
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/recordings/music recordings/Audio recording 2017-02-06 00-21-23.amr (Permission denied)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1088)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1039)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at com.example.studerande.upg32.MainActivity.audioPlayer(MainActivity.java:105)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at com.example.studerande.upg32.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:95)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6917)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>   02-06 00:21:28.636 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   02-06 00:21:28.637 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>   02-06 00:21:28.637 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>   02-06 00:21:28.637 12308-12308/com.example.studerande.upg32 E/MYAPP: exception
>                                                                        java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/recordings/music recordings/Audio recording 2017-02-06 00-21-23.amr (Permission denied)
>                                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
>                                                                            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1088)
>                                                                            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1039)
>                                                                            at com.example.studerande.upg32.MainActivity.audioPlayer(MainActivity.java:105)
>                                                                            at com.example.studerande.upg32.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6917)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

My java code of the mainactivity:

```
    package com.example.studerande.upg32;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RECORDING_ACTIVE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button recordbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_button);

        recordbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button record_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_button);
                record_button.setText("starting recording..");
                startRecord();
            }
        });
    }

    public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
        File file = null;
        try {
            String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
            file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error while creating file
        }
        return file;
    }

    public void startRecord()
    {
        // NOTE THAT THE USER MUST HAVE A RECORDING SOFTWARE. NOT ALL DEVICES HAVE THIS.
        Intent recordingApplicationIntent = new Intent();
        recordingApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
        startActivityForResult(recordingApplicationIntent, RECORDING_ACTIVE);
    }
    private String getAudioFilePathFromUri(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == RECORDING_ACTIVE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Context context;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sound recoding intent success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String thefilename = "";

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            String filePath = getAudioFilePathFromUri(uri);

            thefilename = filePath;
            Button record_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_button);
            record_button.setText(thefilename);


            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);
            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                Log.e("recordapp", "file does not exist");
               // return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("recordapp", "File exist");
                audioPlayer(filePath);
            }
        }

    }
    public void audioPlayer(String path){
        //set up MediaPlayer
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path); // + File.separator + fileName
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }




}
```

I have the permissions of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my android manifest file.

Comment: `if (!sourceFile.isFile()) `. Better:`if (!sourceFile.exists()) `.

Comment: Which Android version running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35285667/4993283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you run app on android API 23+. Because all permissions from manifest are [dangerous](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous) permissions so you need to request it in runtime. [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Some example:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    // PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have said that yes, I am running at API 24. Thank you for telling me this.